# Javascript: Array element display depending on index

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm very new in the coding world and my question is:
I have 2 arrays

```
var user = ['Admin', 'Sarah', 'Kellan', 'Kayliah', 'Kesiah', 'Chloe', 'Keba'];
var valid = ['free', 'free', 'free', 'reject', 'free', 'free', 'reject'];
```

I want that anytime the word "reject" is in the array, the corresponding name is displayed.
For this example, the corresponding names will be Kayliah and Keba.
How do I do that please?

Comment: what would you set up the code? did you try anything so far? BTW, there are no multidimensional array here.

Comment: Can you conceptualise how this might work, in pseudo-code?

Comment: ```console.log(user.filter((el,i)=>valid[i]==='reject').join(','))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple javascript `for` loop should do the trick

```
var user = ['Admin', 'Sarah', 'Kellan', 'Kayliah', 'Kesiah', 'Chloe', 'Keba'];
var valid = ['free', 'free', 'free', 'reject', 'free', 'free', 'reject'];
for (var i = 0; i < valid.length; i++) {
  if (valid[i] == 'reject') {
    Display(user[i]);
  }
}
```

not sure what to do about "Display" though ... how do you want to "Display" it? Guess you can fill in that function yourself

Answer (score 1):

My own approach to this would be to possibly over-complicate it, as follows:

```js
// defining a named Arrow function to handle the retrieval of user-names, the function
// takes two arguments:
// nameValidity: an Array of Objects in which the 'name' property reflects the user-name,
// and the 'validity' property reflects the 'free' or 'reject' value of that user, and
// validity: the value by which you wish to identify the users, this is an option argument
// and has the default of 'free,' on the assumption you're more likely to want to retrieve
// the 'free' users:
const getUsersByValidity = (nameValidity, validity = 'free') => {
  // here we filter the passed-in Array of objects, using
  // Array.prototype.filter():
    return nameValidity.filter(
    // using the anonymous function of the filter() method (in Arrow form), to
    // retain only those objects in the Array wherein the 'validity' property
    // matches the validity you're searching for:
    (obj) => obj.validity === validity
  // filter() returns a modified Array, which we then pass into
  // Array.prototype.map():
  ).map(
    // again using the anonymous function of the method,
    // to create a new Array comprising of the 'name'
    // property-values (the user-names):
    (obj) => obj.name
    // this is then returned to the calling context
  );
};

// original Arrays (though we're declaring variables using the 'let' declaration):
let user = ['Admin', 'Sarah', 'Kellan', 'Kayliah', 'Kesiah', 'Chloe', 'Keba'],
  valid = ['free', 'free', 'free', 'reject', 'free', 'free', 'reject'],
  // here we combine the two Arrays, by calling Array.prototype.map()
  // on the 'user' Array, using the anonymous function which takes two
  // arguments (these variables can be named whatever you like):
  // 'name': a reference to the current array-element, and
  // 'index': the index of the current array-element in the Array:
  userValidity = user.map((name, index) => {
    // here we return an Object:
    return {
      // this creates a property called 'name' and assigns the value
      // of the current array-element as the property-value:
      name,
      // creates the 'validity' property, and retrieves the corresponding
      // value at the same index from the 'valid' Array:
      validity: valid[index]
    };
  });

// here we use console.log() to log the results of the function-call to the console:
console.log(
  // calling the function, passing in the 'userValidity' Array of objects, and searching for
  // those users that have a validity of 'reject':
  getUsersByValidity(userValidity, 'reject')
);
// ["Kayliah","Keba"]
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pwxzLeha/).

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `filter` function to filter the user elements based on your condition:

```js
const user = ['Admin', 'Sarah', 'Kellan', 'Kayliah', 'Kesiah', 'Chloe', 'Keba'];
const valid = ['free', 'free', 'free', 'reject', 'free', 'free', 'reject'];

console.log(user.filter((_item, idx) => valid[idx] === "reject"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript object or use a 2-dimensional array

```
var user_valid = [['Admin', 'Sarah', 'Kellan', 'Kayliah', 'Kesiah', 'Chloe', 'Keba'],['free', 'free', 'free', 'reject', 'free', 'free', 'reject']]
```

then use for-loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < user_valid[0].length; i++) {
  
  if(user_valid[1][i] === "reject"){
console.log(user_valid[0][i],user_valid[1][i]) // it will print kayliah reject
   }
}
```

*JS Object* method-2  *not an array its an object*

```
var object = {
   Admin : 'free',
   sarah : 'free'
// and so on 


}

Object.entries(object).map(pair=>(
  if(pair[1] === "reject"){
   console.log(pair) // ['kayliah' ,'reject']
}
))
```